# How to move one process from SWAP to RAM?

Tags: ram, swap, process, signal

As far as I can see, there is a design error in how my processes are moved between SWAP and RAM:

If RAM gets full, some are moved to SWAP. So far so good. But if RAM gets freed, they are not moved back. This means that they keep using a lot of space (in RAM and/or SWAP) but will never terminate, because in SWAP they only run at less than 1% CPU. So it's kind of a dead-lock.

Is there a way to move specific processes from SWAP to RAM (assume for now there is enough free RAM to accomodate the respective process).

It is not a problem to stop the process before moving to RAM and then continue.

Comment: "...but will never terminate, because in SWAP they only run at less than 1% CPU."  That is not how it works. A process is swapped in as soon as an event occurs that is important for the process. This event can very well be its termination. A swapped out process uses no processor cycles at all (it can't, as it only exists on disk). I don't know where your "1% CPU" comes from.

Comment: It is in D state most of the time so I was thinking it is working at Disk/IO read/write instead of RAM IO, which is much much slower... It could also come from very slowly freeing parts into RAM, seems it is happending at extremely slow rate, and I thought it might be as it is trying to continue running and freeing at the same time....

Comment: It seems that it has moved parts into Swap but not all as the difference between VIRT and RES is much larger in the D state processes as in the running ones, where RES is almost at VIRT

Comment: I think it also has to do with the swappiness as it seems to hesitate to take something out of Swap if there is not a lot of free RAM available